# Category with post type pagination returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, pagination, query-posts

I have a category template with a custom post type that looks like:

```
<?php
    $category = get_query_var('cat');
    $paged = (get_query_var("page")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
    $args = array(
        'cat' => $category,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment'
    );
    query_posts($args);
    $count = $wp_query->found_posts; 
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, "medium"); ?></a>
    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    <?php
        $attachment = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id()); // Get post by ID
        echo '<p>'.$attachment->post_content.'</p>'
    ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <ul class="pagi">
        <li><?php posts_nav_link(' | ','< Previous','Next >'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo "(Page: ". $paged . " of " . $wp_query->max_num_pages .")"; ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Everything is working except the paging...when I view page 2 the url looks like: http://joshrodg.com/ourpictureshare/category/pictures/unknown/page/2/, which is a 404.

I'm not sure what the URL is supposed to look like, but I think the post type in my query is causing the issue.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: A 404 is based on the results of the main query, use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query instead of creating a new query in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

I was able to find a function that modified the query on the category page (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-types-category-pagination-404/#post-1913902 - on the first page toward the bottom, written by: Mark / t31os).

Add this to `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'parse_query','changept' );
function changept() {
    $category = get_query_var('cat');
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if (is_category() && !is_admin())
        set_query_var( 'cat', $category );
        set_query_var( 'paged', $paged );
        set_query_var( 'posts_per_page', 9 );
        set_query_var( 'post_status', 'inherit' );
        set_query_var( 'post_type', 'attachment' );
    return;
}
```

This is what `category.php` looks like now:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, "medium"); ?></a>
    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    <?php
        $attachment = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id()); // Get post by ID
        echo '<p>'.$attachment->post_content.'</p>'
    ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <ul class="pagi">
        <li><?php posts_nav_link(' | ','< Previous','Next >'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo "(Page: ". $paged . " of " . $wp_query->max_num_pages .")"; ?></li>
    </ul>
```

UPDATE:

I ran into a problem with my solution...it was executing on all the pages. All pages except the category page were returning a 404, So I needed to run the code only on the category page to fix the issue.

Here is the updated code `functions.php`:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'category') !== false) {
    add_action( 'parse_query','changept' );
    function changept() {
        $category = get_query_var('cat');
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        if (is_main_query()) {
            set_query_var( 'cat', $category );
            set_query_var( 'paged', $paged );
            set_query_var( 'posts_per_page', 9 );
            set_query_var( 'post_status', 'inherit' );
            set_query_var( 'post_type', 'attachment' );
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Basically, this checks to see if the word "category" is part of the url, and because I am only using this on my `category.php` page, this will work without affecting any other page. There is probably a better solution out there, but this works for my project. Also, another `if` was added to target the main query: `is_main_query()`...this way if you have other queries on the page, they will still function normally.

I'm sure you can do something similar with `pre_get_posts`, which is Milo's suggestion, but I just couldn't figure out how to use that function with my template.